# Remove expression from pandas dataframe and replace it with NAN values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to remove some pattern, particularly '--', '-', '- -', '-  -' from my dataframe columns and replace it with NaN values.

Help me find solution for the same. Dataframe is given below:

[Data frame image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWC3j.png)

Comment: Just use `df['Grade'] = df['Grade'].str.replace('--', np.nan)`

Comment: @MayankPorwal that won't work you can't have NaN as `repl` in `str.replace`, one should rather use `df.replace(r'-+', np.nan, regex=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Well I quickly found out a way to replace this pattern:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
  for j in range(len(df.columns)):
    if df.iloc[i][j] == '--':
      print(df.iloc[i][j])
  
      df.iloc[i,j] = np.nan
```

I hope this helps.